# Android studio emulator cannot run

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

[image]

Does anybody know what is the reason?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the Android Emulator v25.3.2 ? If so, are you running 32-bit windows or 64-bit windows? What were the steps that got you to that state?

Comment: How can I check Android Emulator version? I use 32-bit window. As I click the green triangle button to run,and choose the Galaxy Nexus API, then it come out a android with black screen and next appear that box

Comment: To check the emulator version, you can go the SDK Manager and look for the following line: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzWK0F0x8GNDZDJyRk5vVWQzTDQ/view  After updating to the latest emulator and system images, also ensure you have updated your graphics drivers as well. Once you have done that, create a fresh AVD and make sure you set the RAM size no bigger than 512MB.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable Anti-Virus in your pc and then run emulator again. If that don't work, visit this link and follow the steps, it should work.